# Form does not save value to variable

Tags: forms, configuration

I'm loosing my head. This is the function for generating my admin form:

```
function section_description_and_images_settings() {
  $form = array();

  $form['images_style'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#title' => t('Set default images style'),
    '#options' => array(
      0 => t('Bootstrap columns'),
      1 => t('Slideshow'),
    ),
  '#default_value' => variable_get('section_description_and_images_images_style', 0),
);

  dsm(variable_get('section_description_and_images_images_style', 0));
  return system_settings_form($form);
}
```

And variable section_description_and_images_images_style does not store the desirable value. It's always 0, whether I set 0 or 1.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable name is "images_style" in your case

Comment: Gosh! So, that's how it works. The name of the variable is the name of form field. Why couldn't I find it anywhere? I've no idea why no one has mentioned that. Thank you for saving my time and variable :)